# Mailboxer + Rails 4.1: Message to myself shows duplicate sentbox and inbox message in conversation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mailboxer

Using mailboxer gem version 0.12.2 with Rails version 4.1.4.

When I send a message to myself, the Conversation view shows the same message twice (once as a `mailbox_type`=`sentbox` and once as an `mailbox_type`=`inbox`). I do not have this issue with messages sent to other users.

I simply just want to show the message once in my conversation view (ideally the `inbox` version when viewing my inbox and the `sentbox` version when viewing my sent messages.) Is there a way I can do that?

Here's my `show` action in my custom `ConversationsController` (`current_user` is a devise method indicating the currently signed in user)

```
def show
  @mailbox = current_user.mailbox
  @conversation = @mailbox.conversations.find(params[:id])
  @receipts = @conversation.receipts_for(current_user)
end
```

I've also tried the following combinations within my `show` action, all with the same results.

- Using the `inbox` method instead of the `conversations` method:
  `@conversation = @mailbox.inbox.find(params[:id])`
- Using `receipts_for` method on the `@mailbox` instance variable:
  `@receipts = @mailbox.receipts_for(@conversation)`

Here's my corresponding `show.html.erb` view

```
<ul>
  <%= content_tag_for(:li, @receipts) do |receipt| %>
    <% message = receipt.message %>
    <strong>From:</strong> <%= message.sender.email %>
    <br/>
    <strong>Message:</strong><%= simple_format h message.body %>
    <strong>Sent:</strong> <%= @conversation.updated_at.strftime("%a, %m/%e/%Y %I:%M %p") %>

    <div>
      <br/>DEBUG INFO:<br/>
      Message Id <%= message.id %><br/>
      Receipt Id <%= receipt.id %><br/>
      Receipt Mailbox type <%= receipt.mailbox_type %><br/>
    </div>
    <hr/>

  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Is there anyway to just get my "inbox" view for conversations with myself not to show duplicate messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to searsaw for answering this question on the [gem's github page](https://github.com/mailboxer/mailboxer):

```
def show
  @mailbox = current_user.mailbox
  @conversation = Mailboxer::Conversation.find(params[:id])
  @receipts = @conversation.receipts_for(current_user).inbox
end
```

The line that did it is `@conversation.receipts_for(current_user).inbox`. Calling `inbox` on the `receipts` "[gets the receipts for a logged in user from that conversation that are labeled with the mailbox_type of `inbox`.](https://github.com/mailboxer/mailboxer/issues/297)"

### Limitations

Unfortunately, the contents of the `@receipts` variable for the Conversation's `show` view might not be desirable for conversations with other users if you use the `inbox` method on `receipts` - the `current_user`'s sent messages will not be visible in the Conversation's `show` view with other users. This is a limitation of the mailboxer gem (Mailboxer was not designed with being able to send messages only to yourself).

In the end, extra logic in the controller/view will be needed if you need to support sending messages to only yourself.